# Validating a Date - m/d/yyyy Doesn't Match mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: ruby, datetime, time, format, evaluate

I have a ruby script that checks a provided date, to make sure it is today's date.  This is not working when the date provided doesn't have a 2 digit padding for the month.  Is there anyway to get ruby to see that as equal?  The example is that it says "Date Processed 3/13/2014 is not today's date 03/13/2014!"  the difference is in the month - 3 vs 03.  Below is the code.  ev_val is provided from a csv and it is m/d/yyyy format.  It is not provided with a 0 padding, though.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

```
tnow = Time.now
        if ev_val != tnow.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            log_linemsg = "Date Processed #{ev_val} is not today's date #{tnow.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}! Processing date must be today's Date!!!\nSTOPPING SCRIPT!!!"
            log_line = ["#{$cname}","#{log_linemsg}","","",]
            puts log_linemsg
            insert_logitems(connection, table_namelog, log_line)
            exit
        end
```

Comment: you're doing string comparisons, since the strings have different formats, you'll never get equality for days/months <= 9.

Answer (score 0):

require "date"

date_val = Date.parse ev_val

today = Date.today

if today != date_val

```
log_linemsg = "Date Processed #{ev_val} is not today's date #{today}! Processing date must be today's Date!!!\nSTOPPING SCRIPT!!!"
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Since you only care about the date portion, I would use Date instead of Time.
Take your input string and parse it into a Date object, then compare it to today's date.

```
?> date_val = Date.parse('3/13/2014')
=> Thu, 13 Mar 2014
>> date_val == Date.today
=> true
```

In your example Date.parse(ev_val) != Date.today should work for the comparison.